# Zend: setBelongsTo no working right

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

'm trying to use setBelongsTo in form, but Zend does not validate the values ​​and not setDefaults that field. Have searched on google and found nothing. Any idea?

**Form:**

```
$this->setName('form_tecnicos')
         ->setAttrib('onSubmit',"return validarForm()");



    $elementos['nome'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nome');
    $elementos['nome']->setLabel('Nome')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttrib('maxlength','150');


        $elementos['telefone0'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('0');
        $elementos['telefone0']->setLabel('Telefones')
           ->setRequired(true)
           ->setAttribs(array('mascara'=>'tel','maxlength'=>14))
           ->setBelongsTo('telefones');

        $elementos['telefone1'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('1');
        $elementos['telefone1']->setLabel('Telefones')
           ->setRequired(true)
           ->setAttribs(array('mascara'=>'tel','maxlength'=>14))
           ->setBelongsTo('telefones');

$elementos['submit'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Entrar');
        $elementos['submit']->setLabel('Entrar');

    $this->addElements($elementos);

    $filters = array('StringTrim');
    $this->setElementFilters($filters);

    $this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'viewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd')),
            array('Label',array('tag'=>'dt')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'grid_2'))
    ));


    $remover_label = array('submit');

    foreach($remover_label as $elementos)
        $this->$elementos->removeDecorator('label');
```

**Controller**

```
$form = new Application_Form_Tecnicos();
   $this->view->form = $form;

   if($this->getRequest()->isPost()):
        $dados = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if($form->isValid($dados)):
            //
        else:                   
            $form->setDefaults($dados);
        endif;
   endif;
```

**Print_r($dados)**

```
Array ( [nome] => [telefones] => Array ( [0] => (11) 1111-111 ) [Entrar] => Entrar )
```

**I'm stuck on it**

Comment: My experience of forms in Zend Framework 1 leads me to believe that they're fundamentally broken, especially when working with subforms.

Comment: Broken or probably more nicely worded: Limited. First reverse engineer, then use I can suggest as well.

Comment: I think I'm the only person who likes ZF1 forms. They have their quirks, but they're powerful and make it make it easy to create consistent forms without having to repeat loads of markup. I agree there are some issues with subforms though, and the only good reason I know of to use setBelongsTo is if you need to maintain markup from a legacy app.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues which are actually unrelated to `setBelongsTo`. If you just want the short answer, change the relevant part of your form code to this which works:

```
$elementos['nome'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nome');
$elementos['nome']->setLabel('Nome')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setAttrib('maxlength','150');

$elementos['telefone0'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('telefone0');
$elementos['telefone0']->setLabel('Telefones')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setAttribs(array('mascara'=>'tel','maxlength'=>14))
    ->setBelongsTo('telefones');

$elementos['telefone1'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('telefone1');
$elementos['telefone1']->setLabel('Telefones')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setAttribs(array('mascara'=>'tel','maxlength'=>14))
    ->setBelongsTo('telefones');
```

Here's the longer explanation:

There are two ways you can add form elements to a Zend Form object. You can either instantiate the relevant form element object and add that to the form:

```
$form->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name'));
```

or you can call addElement with the relevant params and get it to create the object for you:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'name');
```

If you use the first approach, it gets the element name from the object. If you use the second, you are passing in the name as the second parameter. The name is what Zend_Form uses internally to store the element, and it's also how it knows which submitted data relates to which element.

When you add elements all at once with `addElements()`, it will use the array key (if non-numeric) as the name. So your first issue is that this:

```
$elementos['telefone0'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('0');
```

stores the name as `telefone0`, but the actual form element uses the name `0`. So when the form is submitted it always fails validation because Zend_Form is expecting the data to be in `$_POST['telefone0']`.

Your second issue is much simpler. Form element names need to work as PHP variables, so you can't use a numeric name (such as the 0 and 1 you had for the telephone fields).

In the working code above all that was required was changing the names of the two telephone elements to match the key in `$elemntos`, which fixes both problems.